# Intercept system wide WM_INPUT messages using RAW INPUT

Tags: c#, usb, barcode-scanner, raw-input

I have a barcode scanner and I am using RAWINPUT to fire a WM_INPUT message which I am intercepting.

However the checkout software I am working on is running on a Windows PC which is used for other things. The checkout is minimised to the system tray when not in use but as soon as something is scanned it pops up.

This all works, however the WM_INPUT event is being passed to the active application for example a word document which is not desirable. Is there any way to block this? Can the message be cancelled after use and not passed on?

I know this has been covered before slightly in this question.

[Win32: Get device info in WH_KEYBOARD_LL || Block input on WM_INPUT when using Raw Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557626/win32-get-device-info-in-wh-keyboard-ll-block-input-on-wm-input-when-using-r)

I don't mind if I have to write a bit of C++ code to handle the scanner and then wrap it. But I need to find a solution. I can use hooks in C# but the problem is they do not identify the originating device like the RAW INPUT model does.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.